# Filepath to Documents folder independent of User

Tags: windows-10, filepath, knime

Is there a way to construct a filepath that links to the Documents folder of the active user. So instead of C:\Users\User\Documents\ something like C:\Active_User\Documents\

ps. I try to make use of this in KNIME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file chooser elements in KNIME understand a URL in the form of "knime://knime.workflow" which accesses the current workflow location regardless of higher directory path.

You could also use a Java Variable Edit to get the username in Java, which you use to create a string that can be used by the File Reader (or other node) as a flow variable.

Comment: I already used the second option you gave. Works like a charm indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve.

You can use

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents
```

which will use the environment variable `%USERNAME%` (= current user).

Comment: For me this looks like the most suitable answer. However the application I am using (KNIME) doesn't evaluate this as a propper filepath, which I was hoping it would. It runs on Java I believe, perhaps that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In C#/.NET you can use `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}",
                     Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
```

In Java `System.getProperty("user.home");` should give you the right base diretory to start with.